# Well typed store with two different store typings

Tags: type-theory

In the book `Types and Programming Languages` by Pierce, exercise `13.5.2` asks for a context $\Gamma$, a store $\mu$ and two different store typings $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ such that the store $\mu$ is well-typed with regards to both store typings, meaning $\Gamma \vert \Sigma_1 \vdash \mu$ as well as $\Gamma \vert \Sigma_2 \vdash \mu$.

The solution says that for the store

$$ \mu = (l \to \lambda x:\mathit{Unit}.(!l)(x)) $$

Both store typings

\begin{align}
\Sigma_1 & = l:\mathit{Unit}\rightarrow\mathit{Unit} \\
\Sigma_2 & = l:\mathit{Unit}\rightarrow(\mathit{Unit}\rightarrow\mathit{Unit})
\end{align}

make $\mu$ well-typed. The language in use is the simply-typed lambda calculus with Unit and references, where $!v$ dereferences $v$ if $v$ is a location.

The book formerly established that general recursion cannot be typed with simple types and the fact that "*following the indirection $l$ yields a function that itself follows the very same indirection*" makes the term seem to be mutually recursive. In other words, the store looks cyclic to me and I don't see how any of the two store typings are applicable such that $\mu$ could be considered to be well-typed.

Could someone please clarify:

1. why the term $\lambda x:\mathit{Unit}.(!l)(x)$ is typable
2. how evaluation of term $!l\ unit$ would terminate
3. how the theorem of the uniqueness of types is not violated even though $\mu(l)$ seems to be in $\Sigma_1(l)$ **and** $\Sigma_2(l)$